# How to set font failover for Vietnamese characters

Tags: fonts

To display a text "**`tiếng Việt`**" (which means Vietnamese), I tried this:

```
(set-fontset-font t '(#x1e00 . #x1eff) "Consolas")
```

but it did not work.

- `describe-char` shows: "**`ế`**" ⇒ `1ebf` "**`ệ`**" ⇒ `1ec7`, so they are within the `#x1e00` - `#x1eff` range.
- I've read a lot about setting fonts in Emacs, but could not find the reason why. I've tested in `emacs -q` too. No luck.
- `(set-frame-font "Consolas")` works, but it is not what I want (because it's not font failover, apparently).
- `(set-fontset-font t 'han "Microsoft Yahei UI")` works for Chinese characters.

Please help. How to set font failover for Vietnamese characters? I am using Emacs in Linux.

Comment: The 4th argument to `set-fontset-font` is best specified using `font-spec`, ie `(font-spec :family "Consolas")`